# File download on IIS6 failing wth Connection_Abandoned when file is over 40mb and no UrlScan installed

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have a server that is failing to download files over 40mb from IIS6 on Windows Server 2003.  The HTTPERR log shows Connection_Abandoned.  The request does not show in the IIS log.  Fiddler shows that no response was received from the server.  There's no error in the event log.  UrlScan is not installed.

We've tried directly linking to the files and also downloading through an ASP.NET page that serves the file (not a redirect, it uses `Response.WriteFile`.  We've tried several files, everything under 40mb works and everything over 40mb fails.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a maxRequestLength issue.  You should be to update web.config: http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/09/24/from-iis6-maxrequestlength-to-iis7-maxallowedcontentlengthfile-specifying-maximum-file-upload-size.aspx
-Chris

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  MaxRequestLength is for upload.  The problem I'm having is with downloads.

Comment: Hi Sam, you are totally correct, I think I was thinking of AspBufferingLimit. Sorry bout that!